# Advanced SelectionSort - Search two elements in one iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm, selection-sort

I've got a homework where I have to "improve" SelectionSort with following parameters:

- Sorting an given list with an "improved" SelectionSort
- In one iteration, finding the smallest and 2nd smallest element
- Bring the smallest and 2nd smallest element in the right position.

Ok so far I wrote this c++ code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int min, min2;

    // doesn't work
    array<int, 9> list = { 97,34,15,25,27,4,19,41,68 };

    /* this one works:
    array<int, 10> list = { 4,8,1,3,10,6,5,7,9,2 }; 
    */

    // First loop
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
        min = i;
        min2 = i + 1;

        // 2nd Loop for searching the smallest elements
        for (int j = i + 2; j < list.size(); j++) {

            if (list.at(j) < list.at(min)) {
                min = j;
            }

            // outer if -> stop before out of array
            if (j+1 < list.size()) {
                if (list.at(j+1) < list.at(min2)) {
                    min2 = j+1;
                }
            }   
        }
        swap(list.at(i), list.at(min));
        // Prevent out of array error
        if (i + 1 < list.size()) {
            swap(list.at(i+1), list.at(min2));
        }
    }

    cout << '\n' << '\n';
    cout << "Sorted list: " << endl;
    for (int elem : list) {
        cout << elem << ", ";
    }
  }
```

Of course it's sorting and this is the result... but not the one I was hoping for:

**4, 97, 15, 19, 25, 34, 27, 41, 68,**

I'm out of ideas and the only hint I got was: "no third loop".

I would appreciate any help :-)

**EDIT:**

Due the voting to hold on I try to specify the problem.
When I'm using high int-values for example the ones in the code, the sorting-algorithm doesn't work properly

- List: `array<int, 9> list = { 97,34,15,25,27,4,19,41,68 };`
- Result: `4, 97, 15, 19, 25, 34, 27, 41, 68,`

As you can see the values on position 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 from the first if-statement were sorted properly but the others form the 2nd if-statement not.

When I change the int values for example to values from 1-10 and mix them random, the algorithm seems to work properly (*thanks for the comment!*):

- List: `array<int, 10> list = { 4,8,1,3,10,6,5,7,9,2 };`
- Result: `1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10,`

I'm out of ideas - Is it a programming error or a bad algorithm?

**EDIT 3:**
**Here is my (finally working) updated code:**

```
//array<int, 10> list = { 4,8,1,3,10,6,5,7,9,2 };
//array<int, 4> list = { 97,15,25,18 };
//array<int, 2> list = { 97,18 };
array<int, 3> list = { 4,5,3 };

// First loop
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
    if (i == list.size() - 1) {
        break;
    }
    min = i;
    min2 = i + 1;

    // Enforce that list.at(min) <= list.at(min2) -> Sorting pivot (element) for the algorithm to smallest, 2nd smallest.
    if (list.at(min) > list.at(min2)) {
        swap(list.at(min), list.at(min2));
    }

    // Second Loop
    for (int j = i + 2; j < list.size(); ++j) {
        if (list.at(j) < list.at(min)) {
            min2 = min; // min2 points now on the 2nd smallest element
            min = j; // min points now on the smallest element
        }
        else if (list.at(j) < list.at(min2)) {
            min2 = j;
        }
    }

    // Swapping the elements in the right position.
    swap(list.at(i + 1), list.at(min2));
    swap(list.at(i), list.at(min));
}
```

**Results:**

{ 4,8,1,3,10,6,5,7,9,2 } -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

{ 97,15,25,18 } -> 15, 18, 25, 97,

{ 97,18 } -> 18, 97,

{ 4,5,3 } -> 3, 4, 5,

Comment: Start with 3 or 4 numbers, not 9.

Comment: The first thing you should notice is that in the array that works, `list[0] < list[1]`, and in the array that doesn't work, `list[0] > list[1]`. Your code makes the assumption that `min <= min2`, but you don't enforce it. For example, whenever you find a new `min`, you have to move `min` to `min2`. You don't do that. There are other problems, but all have to do with your failure to enforce `min <= min2`.

Comment: @JimMischel - Thank your for the reply! Just for my understanding: why do I have to enforce the value of `min` to `min2` and does it have to happen in the 2nd for-loop? My first try was to compare `list[0]` with `list[1]` and change the values when `list[0]` > `list[1]` with `if (list.at(min) > list.at(min2)) {   swap(list.at(min), list.at(min2)); }`. I tried it with an array of 4 elements ( 97,18,15,25) and that was the result: 15, 25, 18, 97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your program with the array `[97,18]`. I think you'll find that it doesn't work, because the 2nd loop is never entered, and the lines at the end of the first loop won't swap anything.

When I said in my comment that `min` must be less than or equal to `min2`, I meant to say that you must ensure `list.at(min) <= list.at(min2)`. My example above of the 2-item array shows why that's important.

The way to enforce that is to modify your first loop:

```
// First loop
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
    if (i == list.size()-1) {
        // There is an odd number of items in the list.
        // At this point, we know that the last item is in place.
        // So just exit.
        break;
    }
    min = i;
    min2 = i + 1;

    // enforce list(min) <= list(min2)
    if (list.at(min) > list.at(min2)) {
        swap(list.at(min), list.at(min2));
    }

    // second loop
```

And, yes, you must maintain that in the inner loop. If you try with the array `[4,5,3]`, the result will be `[3,5,4]`.

That's primarily because in your inner loop, when you find that `list.at(j) < list.at(min)`, you swap the items. But when `list.at(min2) > list.at(min)`, what you've done is swap things out of order.

You should single-step your code in the debugger using that 3-element list to understand what's happening. If you don't know how to use the debugger, stop right now and learn. This type of programming error is very easy to discover when you can watch a line-by-line execution of your code. The alternative is to do it by hand: with a piece of paper and pencil, walk through the code step by step, writing down the change to every variable.

The other problem with your inner loop is that you're checking `list.at(j+1)` with `list.at(min2)`. But you're only incrementing `j` by 1 each time, so you end up doing extra work. There's no reason to do that extra check. It'll be handled the next time through the loop.

The fix in the inner loop, assuming that you maintain the proper relationship between `min` and `min2`, is easy enough. If `list.at(j) < list.at(min)`, then set `min2=min` (because `min` is now pointing to the second-smallest item), and set `min=j`. If `list.at(j) < list.at(min2)`, then just set `min2=j`. The code looks like this:

```
for (j = i+2; j < list.size(); ++j) {
    if (list.at(j) < list.at(min)) {
        min2 = min;
        min = j;
    } else if (list.at(j) < list.at(min2)) {
        min2 = j;
    }
}
```

Now your code at the end of the outer loop works correctly.

### Debugging

Run your program in the debugger with the array `[4,5,3]`. Place a breakpoint on the line just after the inner loop, here:

```
    swap(list.at(i), list.at(min));
```

If you examine the array, you'll see that it's still `[4,5,3]`. But look at `min` and `min2`. You'll see that `min=2` and `min2=0`. `i` is equal to `0`. Now, what happens when when you swap the items at `list[i]` and `list[min]`? You get `[3,5,4]`, and `min2` no longer points to the second smallest item.

There are several different conditions in which something like this can happen. You have to think of those conditions, and handle them. The code I provided lets you find the smallest and 2nd smallest items. But you have to figure out how to swap things into the correct places after you've found them.

Comment: Thank you for the comment .. really good and I tried the debugger and I think I realized how it works... but still - even your code doesn't work... When I use it I get the mentioned `3,5,4` but than min2 get the value of min (0) and during the 2nd swap `if (i + 1 < list.size()) { swap(list.at(i + 1), list.at(min2));}` 3 and 5 will be swapped to `5,3,4` ... this code seriously drives me crazy

Comment: m3ow Did you make the change at the top of your outer loop to enforce that `list.at(min) <= list.at(min2)`? See my modified answer, which shows that. I don't see how, in `[3,5,4]`, `min2` could ever be assigned 0. The first time through the inner loop, `list.at(j)` is not less than `list.at(min)`. But it is less than `list.at(min2)`. So it should assign `min2=2`.

Comment: I've updated my first post with the provided code... as you can see.. still strange sorting. Even when I debug it. I'm curious

Comment: After a "little" break I reviewed the code, reviewed your hints, learned to debug and finally made it. The key was the swapping. In the Example with `[4, 5, 3]` I swapped after the inner loop the elements 5 with 4 -> `swap(list.at(i + 1), list.at(min2));` and after that 5 with 3 -> `swap(list.at(i), list.at(min));` and yeeeey it finally works with all kind of arrays. Have a look at my `EDIT 3 Code`. Thank you sooooooo much Jim!